# Appcelerator IOS App will not link after upgrade to XCode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcelerator, xcode8

I've upgraded my Appcelerator Studio to Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.8.1.201612050850 and my Xcode to version to 8.2.1 and have an app that is targeting SDK 6.0.1.  My project worked fine before the upgrade but now will not run on my attached IOS device.  When I run to my device I get the following error in my appcelerator console

```
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/Stackfish.build/Debug-iphoneos/Stackfish.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Stackfish normal arm64
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

When I open the project in Xcode I can see there is an issue linking.  Here's the Xcode error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TiMediaItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in    libcom.furthergone.mediapicker.a(ComFurtherGoneMediaPickerModule.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my module's titanium.xconfig

```
 TITANIUM_SDK_VERSION = 6.0.1.GA
 TITANIUM_SDK = /Users/jimbrazil/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA
 TITANIUM_BASE_SDK = "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include"
 TITANIUM_BASE_SDK2 = "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include/TiCore"
 TITANIUM_BASE_SDK3 = "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include/JavaScriptCore"
 HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS= $(TITANIUM_BASE_SDK) $(TITANIUM_BASE_SDK2)    $(TITANIUM_BASE_SDK3)
```

I'm not an Xcode developer and can't figure out why my app won't link any more.  Does anyone have an idea what the issue is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like appcelerator changed some rules.  I needed to add

```
 #ifndef USE_TI_MEDIAQUERYMUSICLIBRARY
 #define USE_TI_MEDIAQUERYMUSICLIBRARY
 #endif
```

in my module.xconfig to compile in the Media classes